# Running a for loop on list and save results in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to run for each element in the list the for loop and have a data frame with the first column i from list and the following the element from wordnet.

active active active_voice
nice   nice   decent

```
synonyms = []
list = ["active", "decent"] 

for i in list:
 for syn in wordnet.synsets(i):
    for l in syn.lemmas():
        synonyms.append(i)   
        synonyms.append(l.name())
```

Instead of I am receiving a list in which the first element "active" was running twice through the loop.

Comment: Can you provide a sample data set and expected output?

Comment: How did you use ```list``` as a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is basically correct, but there are many duplicates in the synonym list as you are constructing it.  I've modified it below to build up a list of pairs to put in the dataframe.

```py
import nltk
wordnet = nltk.wordnet.wordnet

# Words to lookup.
words = ["active", "decent"]

# Build a list of pairs, word:synonym
synonyms = []
for i in words: 
    for syn in wordnet.synsets(i): 
         for l in syn.lemmas():
             synonyms.append((i, l.name())) 

df = pd.DataFrame(sorted(synonyms), columns=('word', 'synonym'))
df.drop_duplicates()
```

which produces

```
0   active         active
17  active   active_agent
18  active   active_voice
19  active          alive
20  active   combat-ready
21  active        dynamic
22  active       fighting
23  active  participating
24  decent       adequate
25  decent       becoming
26  decent         comely
27  decent  comme_il_faut
28  decent         decent
35  decent       decently
36  decent       decorous
37  decent         enough
38  decent  in_good_order
39  decent           nice
40  decent       properly
41  decent          right
42  decent         seemly
43  decent  the_right_way
```

You can instead get rid of the duplicates ahead of time by building sets

```py
synonyms = {}
for i in words:
   entries = set()
   for syn in wordnet.synsets(i):
       for l in syn.lemmas():
           entries.add(l.name())
   synonyms[i] = entries

pairs = ((k,v) for k,entries in sorted(synonyms.items()) 
         for v in sorted(entries))
df = pd.DataFrame(pairs, columns=('name', 'synonym'))
df
```

which produces

```
      name        synonym
0   active         active
1   active   active_agent
2   active   active_voice
3   active          alive
4   active   combat-ready
5   active        dynamic
6   active       fighting
7   active  participating
8   decent       adequate
9   decent       becoming
10  decent         comely
11  decent  comme_il_faut
12  decent         decent
13  decent       decently
14  decent       decorous
15  decent         enough
16  decent  in_good_order
17  decent           nice
18  decent       properly
19  decent          right
20  decent         seemly
21  decent  the_right_way
```